# Analytic continuation of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$f(z) = A_0 + A_1(z-a) + A_2(z-a)^2 + \cdots$$

converge in some disk $|z - a| < r$. [Following Weyl](http://books.google.ie/books?id=AlPVP13Wb08C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false), we magically re-arrange this power series at point $b$ in this disk and the power series should converge in a disk of radius $r - |b-a|$. If it converges outside this disk, we have an analytically continuation of our function outside it's original disk of convergence.

This is all definitions though, how would you actually do this with ***a few*** explicit examples (preferably ones that capture the spirit of what's going on here, e.g. sums, integrals etc... and not just the standard geometric series example - is that the only one that exists?)

thanks!

Comment: try $\ln(1-x)$? or perhaps $\frac{1}{P(x)}$ for some polynomial of $P(x)$ of your choice. To generate the terms sort them in order of ascending power and perform standard long division. Note that all integrals and derivatives of rational expressions can be evaluated using this technique

Answer (score 5):

The reason that you don't see more examples is that the coefficients of the rearranged series cannot be computed recursively in a finitary way, as with the product or the composition of two series. In general each  coefficient $B_k$ of the rearranged series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k(z-b)^k$ is the sum of an infinite series involving the $A_k$: One has
$$B_n={f^{(n)}(b)\over n!}={1\over n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k\> k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)(b-a)^{k-n}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty{k\choose n}\>A_k\>(b-a)^{k-n}\ .$$

Therefore all examples you can find are "special", in the sense that there is an overriding principle at work (a functional equation for $f$, a differential equation, etc.) that gives you the $B_k$ by some other means.

Here is one such example:
$$f(z):={1\over 1+z^2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\>z^{2j}\qquad\bigl(|z|<1\bigr)\ .$$
Expanding this function at the point $b:=1$ instead of $a:=0$ gives
$$f(z)={1\over2}-{1\over2}(z-1)+{1\over4}(z-1)^2-{1\over8}(z-1)^4+{1\over8}(z-1)^5-{1\over16}(z-1)^6+{1\over32}(z-1)^8-{1\over32}(z-1)^9+{1\over64}(z-1)^{10}-\ldots\ ,$$
where it is not difficult to detect the law of coefficients. (Note that there are no terms of degree $4j-1$.) The rearranged series has radius of convergence $\sqrt{2}$, and converges, e.g., for $z:=2$, where the original series is no longer valid.

Comment: So are you telling me that analytic continuation of a series involves summing up that series (defined on a small domain), e.g. summing up $\sum (-1)^jz^{2j}$, to get a function expression for that series, $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$, and then constructing it's Taylor series at a new point which is not inside the radius of convergence of the original series? Is that the general method? Obviously if you can't sum the series then it becomes a theoretical method, but when you can sum it then that's the method?

Comment: Sorry I would have given the full 50 if I'd gotten back here in time!

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe a procedure for you to be able to answer your own question:
First, use the infinite geometric sum to expand $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and recall that this sum converges only for $z$ within the unit disk. Next, simply take the derivative on both sides. By analytic continuation, your derivative can be defined for all complex $z$ except for 1. Use your result to determine the "value" of $$1-2+3-4+5-6+\cdots $$ I write "value" in quotations since this sum diverges, so the value only applies under the analytic continuation.